# What do you call the act of moving sideways by jumping and extending your legs in a V before jumping?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of moving sideways by jumping and extending your legs in a V before jumping? By that I mean extending your legs in a V and then putting your legs together while jumping so as to form an I and on and on? Is there a particular name for this? I am thinking there might be one since kids do that a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of [**jumping jacks**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jumping%20jacks)—but you forgot to mention that your arms are also lifted outward in combination with your legs:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a conditioning exercise performed from a standing position by jumping to a position with legs spread and arms raised and then to the original position
>   // We did a few *jumping jacks* to warm up.

[image: jumping jack]

Also, you don't normally move from your original position.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re describing is a Carioca running drill. It’s like you’re running sideways or skipping sideways. My little brother does that a lot in our apartment and everyday I tell him to stop but you know little kids don’t listen. Anyways, I hope I answered your question.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as you never really make a V with your legs while doing a Carioca running drill.  This drill is more about the hips and crossing your legs rather than spreading them apart.